# UI-Router resolve sending promise to controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to resolve a few pieces of linked data with UI-Router. The `bar` function works fine, and resolves the promise by the time it reaches the controller, but the `drinkers` function sends a promise to the controller.

The resolved `bar` variable is an object with a `drinkers` array, and I'm trying to resolve the drinkers separately, so that all the information is available at the controller.

How can I get it to resolve correctly? Here's what I've got in my routing config:

```
resolve: {
    bar: function(api, $stateParams) {
        return new api.getBar($stateParams.id);
    },
    drinkers: ['bar', 'api', function(bar, api) {
        return bar.drinkers.map(function(element){
            return new api.getDrinker(element.id);
        });
    }]
}
```

Comment: are you returning multiple promises from `drinkers`?

Comment: I'm not even sure if having a resolve function depending on another one is valid. But if it is, you should not return an array of promises from drinkers, but a promise: `return $q.all(bar.drinkers.map(function(element){
            return new api.getDrinker(element.id);
        }));`

Comment: FYI resolves can indeed depend on other resolves

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LzjV7yJtv8AQuprxNBKi?p=preview)

I would say, that you are almost there, just do not use **`new`** keyword. This is related to constructor functions (which I would not expect here), not to usual function call:

```
  resolve : {
    bar: ['api', '$stateParams', function(api, $stateParams) {
      // instead of this
      // return new api.getBar($stateParams.id);
      // just use this
      return api.getBar($stateParams.id);
    }],
    drinkers: ['bar', 'api', function(bar, api) {
      return bar.drinkers.map(function(element) {
        // no new call
        // return new api.getDrinker(element.id);
        // just this
        return api.getDrinker(element.id); 
      });
    }]
  }
```

In case, that both services do return promises in the get methods, we would need to extend the array processing with `$q.all()`

```
  resolve : {
    bar: ['api', '$stateParams', function(api, $stateParams) {
      return api.getBar($stateParams.id);
    }],
    drinkers: ['bar', 'api', '$q', function(bar, api, $q) {

      var promises = bar.drinkers.map(function(element){
        return api.getDrinker(element.id);
      });

      return $q.all(promises);
    }]
  } 
})
```

Try to check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LzjV7yJtv8AQuprxNBKi?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems here. The first is that one is your resolves depends on the other, which is not good since they execute in parallel. The second is that the drinkers resolve returns multiple promises.

To solve the first problem, combine both resolves into single one and chain the second onto the first.

To solve the second problem, use q.all to execute the getDrinker request in parallel and get a single result.

Here is pseudo-codes solution to both:

```
resolve: {
    data: function(api, $stateParams, $q)  {
        return api.getBar($stateParams.id)
            .then(function(resp) {
                var bar = resp.data, reqArr = [];

                 bar.drinkers.forEach(function(d) {
                     reqArr.push(api.getDrinker(d.id));
                 });

                 $q.all(reqArr).then(function(drinkers) {
                     return {
                         bar:bar,
                         drinkers:drinkers
                     };
                 });
             });
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, inject `data` and use `data.bar` and `data.drinkers`.